# Adding “/“ on birthday input, but delete “/“ when delete is pressed

Tags: jquery, html, jscript

I have this code that adds a “/“ when the length of birthday is 2. But when delete is pressed it keeps adding the “/“ but I don’t want this to happen, I want to delete the slash and the previous number.

```
$("#birthday").keyup(function (){
    var bLenght = $("#birthday").val().length
    console.log(bLenght);

    if (bLenght === 2 || bLenght == 5) {
        console.log(bLenght);
        $("#birthday").val($("#birthday").val()+"/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$("#birthday").keyup(function (e){
    if(e.which !== 46 && e.which !== 8)
    {
        var bLenght = $("#birthday").val().length
        console.log(bLenght);

    if (bLenght === 2 || bLenght == 5) {
        console.log(bLenght);
        $("#birthday").val($("#birthday").val()+"/");
    }
}
});
```

Your problem is, when you press backspace or delete, it removes the forward-slash. You then release the key, and because there are two characters, the forward slash is re-added. I added an if block which checks if the key released was backspace(8) or delete(46) so that you don't get stuck in that loop.

Comment: Works great! But I need to delete also the previous number to the slash

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question. You can type "00" then backspace and remove it all. Would you mind describing your problem more in depth?

Comment: What I mean is when the val( ) is “12/” and delete is pressed the value returns to “1” or when the value is “12/02/“ and delete is pressed the value returns to “12/0” like the slash does not count in the value.